# Openshift free account setup local environment

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I am using free plan from Openshift Paas for my applications. I want to set up openshift environment on my local machine so that I don't have any issues while setting up my app on live environment. I will configure the app on local and then push the code to production server, i.e the Openshift server.

Is it possible with the free plan? I am sure you can set up the Openshift Origin on your local machine using Vagrant/Docker but I have a doubt, if I will be able to push my changes on server using it?

Answer (score 0):

Using your Vagrant/Docker instance on your local machine, you will be able to tie that to Github and you can pull from there. Since your local machine's IP is unlikely to be exposed on the internet, Github cannot see you: so the webhook from Github will not work to trigger automatic re-builds.

Still, that's probably a minor thing if you are just experimenting. With a few clicks, you can go to the build and click to re-build.